# Finding a median of 3 values using SSE2 instruction set

Tags: c, algorithm, sse2

My input data is 16-bit data, and I need to find a median of 3 values using SSE2 instruction set.

If I have 3 16-bits input values A, B and C, I thought to do it like this:

```
D = max( max( A, B ), C )
E = min( min( A, B ), C )
median = A + B + C - D - E
```

C functions I am planing to use are :

- max - _mm_max_epi16
- min - _mm_min_epi16
- addition - _mm_add_epi16
- subtract - _mm_sub_epi16

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea is quite clever but you can do it with fewer operations just using max and min.

```
t1 = min(A, B)
t2 = max(A, B)
t3 = min(t2, C)
median = max(t1, t3)
```

This will be just 4 SSE instructions compared with 8 in your original implementation.

Note that this is actually just a pruned [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) for N = 3.